# Making USB work in Wine 4.0 (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: usb, debug, wine

I succeeded in installing a Windows application in [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) (Disco Dingo) (I needed *winetricks* to install [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.5). The application is configuration software for an electronic device with a USB port (BZS config).

The application starts, but it says "no device connected". USB is connected and [lsusb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci#lsusb) shows that device is recognized by the Linux kernel:

```
Bus 001 Device 124: ID 1fc9:81d5 NXP Semiconductors
```

There are plenty of symlinks in dosdevices, e.g.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 <user> <user> 12 Sep  1 17:10 com33 -> /dev/ttyUSB0
```

dmesg says:

```
[420485.204701] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[420492.561108] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 112
[420497.008650] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 113 using xhci_hcd
[420497.166011] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1fc9, idProduct=81d5, bcdDevice= 1.00
[420497.166015] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[420497.166018] usb 1-2: Product: VCOM Port
[420497.166021] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: NZR
[420497.166023] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: NZR-77
```

What are the next steps to try to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pertinent part in the Wine documentation is likely
[Serial and Parallel Ports](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Serial_and_Parallel_Ports),
which describes how to make Wine aware of USB serial devices:

> Make sure you have the needed rights to access your computer's serial
> and parallel ports. On Linux, a user must typically be a member of the
> `sys` or `dialout` group to access serial ports, or the `lp` group to
> access parallel ports.
>
> To override Wine's default device mapping, run `wine regedit` and
> create string entries in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wine\Ports`
> where the entry name is the Windows device name and the entry value is
> the path to the Unix device. Continuing with the above example, to
> make COM1 the first USB-attached serial port, create an entry with the
> name COM1 and the value `/dev/ttyUSB0`.
>
> After editing the registry, shut down Wine with `wineserver -k` and
> the next time Wine runs a program, your changes will take effect.

However, if the USB device requires the installation of a device driver under Windows, then you are just out of luck.

Comment: yes, it does require the installation.

Comment: Wine does not support Windows device drivers, so that might explain why it cannot find the device.

Comment: the question now for me is: did I make a mistake configuring ACM0 in registry, symlinks and group edit or  is it simply impossible?

Comment: If you are sure that this is an [ACM0 device](https://rfc1149.net/blog/2013/03/05/what-is-the-difference-between-devttyusbx-and-devttyacmx/) and it is detected in Linux, then I think you have done everything that is possible.